# Fetch API data from polling service

Tags: javascript, typescript, playwright

How to fetch polling API services data with help of playwright services is polling in every 10secs

Ex: it's Fetching payments status in every 10 secs have different response  like

```
Payment Failed
Payment successful
Wait for Confirmation
```

as and when services starts its have response as Waiting for confirmation
later based on actions made on UI status of this services changes accordingly

Help me to automate this scenario

Tech used : JS/TS with playwright

```
const resquestPromise = page.waitforRequest(URL)
const reposnePromise = page.waitForReponse(URL)
const [request, response ] = await Promise.all([
requestPromise, responsePromise])
let responseData = await response.json();
expect (responseData.message).toBe("Payment successful)"
```

another scenario

```
expect (responseData.message).toBe("payment failed")
```